# Fadeout elements hide elements which fadein

Tags: jquery, ajax, append, fadein, fadeout

i have these html code:

```
  <body>
    <div id="top">
      <div id="panels">
         <div id="yes">yes</div>
         <div id="no">no</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I using jQuery (i`m not a specialist) to fadeout old elements and by ajax adding new (ajax code is not ready now)..so the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#yes').click(function(){
    $('#panels').fadeOut(1000);
    var fun = $('<div>ITS OVER</div>');
    $(fun).hide().appendTo('#panels').fadeIn(1500);
});
});
```

but it works like: i click on the button (#yes) it start to fadeout old elements during this process it fadein new, and when fadeout finish both elements is not displaied, what is the problem?
P.S. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending it to a hidden container `$('#panels').fadeOut(1000);`.

You could just hide the  children `$('#panels').children().fadeOut(1000)` instead of the whole container.

Since your new content would ideally `load` into the container. I am emptying out panels, and adding the dynamic content.

```
$('#panels').fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $(this)
        .html('<div>ITS OVER</div>')
        .fadeIn(1500);
})
```

Comment: +1 This is cleaner with the callback, except that you're appending the new element to the children instead of the `#panels`.

Comment: Actually one more thing to consider. Because there are 2 children, the callback will fire twice creating 2 new elements. EDIT: It may just be simpler to fade `#panels`, hide the children, append the new one, then fade `#panels` back in.